# Step by step guild for Rancher with proxy

Tags: rancher, tinyproxy

We have a new project requirement where wehave to run rancher behind proxy and I'm very much new to the proxy setup with Rancher and trying to understand how proxy flow works with rancher and how to configure it on AWS. I have below setup :

a) 1 ubuntu node where tinyproxy is installed
b) 1 ubuntu node where rancher is installed with helm
c) 1 ubuntu node where custom downstream cluster is installed

As per my understanding, below will be the actual flow :

Browser -> tinyproxy -> rancher -> downstream cluster

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong ?

Question :
a) I have followed few article to install tinybox on EC2 and everyone has talked about configuring the inbound connection to SSH and custom IP i.e Rancher IP but what about the outbound connections?

So, Do I need to open all the outbound connections to all traffic for my tinyproxy server?

i.e Browser <-- (all network) <--tinyproxy(Allow <rancherIP + downstream IP> <----- rancher ----- downstream cluster

b) We have added the HTTP_PROXY, NO_PROXY AND HTTPS_PROXY but how can we confirm the connection is going through the proxy only? currently, our Rancher EC2 install is having all traffic open in inbound/outbound connections.

Thanks in advance.